# DRYest routing config for a non-REST controller and its actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rails-routing

Fairly certain I'm doin' this wrong. How can I DRY it up?

```
controller 'foo' do
  get  'foo/bar', :action => 'bar', :as => 'foo_bar'
  post 'foo/bar', :action => 'bar', :as => 'foo_bar'
  post 'foo/baz', :action => 'baz', :as => 'foo_baz'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rake routes` shows the same routing with this:

```
get 'foo/bar'
post 'foo/bar'
post 'foo/baz'
```

Comment: Okay -- I should note that i actually want the route names preceeded by the controller name ("foo_*") -- I modified the question.

Comment: @JohnBachir I bet you can modify my answer to do that.

Comment: Done. Sadly I think there is no way to avoid typing 'foo' three times.

Comment: @JohnBachir I think there's a point of diminishing returns here-this is easy to understand and obvious.